# HTTP code 400 returned while communication with GCM

Tags: android, apache, http, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement HTTP server for GCM communication. After providing the correct keys , I get HTTP response code as '400'. Here is the code snippet:

```
URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.sgp.com", 8080));
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key="+"AIzaSyAYc53L6kg_XerwoWdLjUAi2iEfNKidSF8");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeUTF("{\"collapse_key\" : \"Food-Promo\", \"data\" : {\"Category\" : \"FOOD\",\"Type\": \"VEG\",}, \"registration_ids\": [\"APA91bEk7GPFVxzOidvB3JKCMWq3FHpAaTj2dBv9VGOQkKtLAEiVGR8TDi1fsU4D1k293ODAFTJ8dNfE2gzJNfCvB1sjewZu2fGOIJmY8dgjcNTZQYi4QfyQH-AaO0qEmQnbEeEtsUQ5LzWrIHboAhJMx1bfdsO9bg\"]}");
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: your json is invalid

Comment: right json "{\"collapse_key\": \"Food-Promo\",\"data\": {\"Category\": \"FOOD\",\"Type\": VEG\"},\"registration_ids\":[ \"APA91bEk7GPFVxzOidvB3JKCMWq3FHpAaTj2dBv9VGOQkKtLAEiVGR8TDi1fsU4D1k293ODAFTJ8dNfE2gzJNfCvB1sjewZu2fGOIJmY8dgjcNTZQYi4QfyQH-AaO0qEmQnbEeEtsUQ5LzWrIHboAhJMx1bfdsO9bg\"]}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

400 error only comes in following case:

Only applies for JSON requests. `Indicates that the request could not be parsed as JSON`, or it contained invalid fields (for instance, passing a string where a number was expected). The exact failure reason is described in the response and the problem should be addressed before the request can be retried.
[Reference](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#response)

So you can try this code, its working for me

Create one POJO class for standard message format for GCM

```
public class Content implements Serializable {

public List<String> registration_ids;
public Map<String,String> data;

public void addRegId(String regId){
    if(registration_ids == null)
        registration_ids = new LinkedList<String>();
    registration_ids.add(regId);
}

public void createData(String title, String message){
    if(data == null)
        data = new HashMap<String,String>();

    data.put("title", title);
    data.put("message", message);
}

}
```

Code to request GCM to send notification message to android device,

```
   String apiKey = ""; //API key provided by Google Console
   String deviceID="";//Device Id
   Content content = new Content();
   //POJO class as above for standard message format
   content.addRegId(deviceID);       
   content.createData("Title", "Notification Message");
   URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
   HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
   conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key="+apiKey);
   conn.setDoOutput(true);
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
   mapper.writeValue(wr, content);
   wr.flush();
   wr.close();
   responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
```

Hope this helps you with your problem...!!!!!